# App run via Qt Creator doesn't prompt for microphone permission on macOS

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator, macos-monterey

When I build and run my application via Qt creator, it doesn't prompt for microphone access and because of that microphone doesn't work within the app.

If I run the built application directly via terminal (`open applicaton.app`) permission prompt similar to the one below is shown without any issues:
[image]

My environment:

- macOS Monterey 12.4 on MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) powered by Apple M1 Pro chip
- Qt 5.12.12 with Qt Creator 5.0.2

This makes it difficult to test my app since every time I build it, I need to run it from the terminal for microphone to work. `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` is present in the Info.plist (otherwise it wouldn't work at all).

I've tried Qt 5.15.2 and everything works fine there (app requests permission when run from Qt Creator), but I need to use 5.12.12 for other reasons.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Can be replicated using Audio Input example that comes with Qt.

Comment: I do not have QtCreator, but Visual Studio code. Is it reproducible from other IDEs or specific to QtCreator?

Comment: It is specific to Qt Creator. I've found the reason for different behaviour between Qt5.12.12 and Qt5.15.2, they explained it here: https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/commit/86783985a03752b2205d7d9ee168051003cb64c4

I guess I can use Qt5.12.12 with newer Qt Creator 8.0 and it will work.

Comment: Hi, did you get your answer or do you still need any further information to get your question answered?

Comment: Note that the fix went into Qt Creator 7, but there is a regression Qt Creator 8.0.0 which broke this again. So this should work like expected in Qt Creator 7.0.x and Qt Creator 8.0.1 (currently only as a snapshot e.g. from https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qtcreator/8.0/8.0.1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because QtCreator was set up without microphone access and child processes running from QtCreator would inherit that setting.

When you run it through the console, the application would be in charge of setting these permissions up for itself as opposed to inheriting it from QtCreator.

It seems that the QtCreator maintainer addressed this issue in QtCreator 8.0.0 [in this commit](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt-creator/qt-creator/+/386978). The issue was originally reported [in this Jira ticket](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26743).

So, the solution is to either use that version or just launch it separately or in a different IDE for the time being.